# Align images to bottom of page

Tags: html, css

This seems to be a common problem but I'm having trouble.
When I set my css with

```
position: absolute; 
bottom: 0;
```

, all my images end up overlapping each other, instead of being displayed next to each other, on the bottom.
How do I fix this?

**Edit:** I can't encase them in their own div because when clicked, the targeted image is supposed to go to the top of the page

```
:target{
 position:absolute; 
 top:0
}
```

Edit: Code::
http://jsfiddle.net/5MXLb/

```
div#main{
    text-align: center;
}

.gallery{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}

.gallery img{
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 10%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;

}
.gallery img:target{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    max-height: 90%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
        <div class="gallery">
            <a href="#img1"><img id="img1" src="http://placehold.it/200" /></a>
            <a href="#img2"><img id="img2" src="http://placehold.it/400" /></a>
            <a href="#img3"><img id="img3" src="http://placehold.it/600" /></a>
            <a href="#img4"><img id="img4" src="http://placehold.it/800" /></a>
            <a href="#img5"><img id="img5" src="http://placehold.it/1000" /></a>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you show the code? If the number of images are limited and width is known, you could consider setting the left also. Or keep images in a div and set the position for the div.

Comment: Try "display:inline-block".

Comment: updated with the code, I do have inline-block already

Comment: A jsfiddle is helpful to understand your problem.

Comment: copy/pasted into jsfiddle for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only targeting newer browsers, you can use flexbox. http://jsfiddle.net/5MXLb/1/

I've only included the `-webkit` prefixed versions.

```
div#main{
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
}
html, body { height: 100%; }
.gallery{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
}
/* this stops the shrinking of the items */
.gallery a {
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
}

.gallery img{
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 10%;

}
.gallery img:target{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    max-height: 90%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

But I think this does what you're looking for.

Comment: This is perfect, except when I have many images they kinda stack on top of each other. See screen-shot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h87exwlutd25h5b/Screen%20Shot%202013-07-19%20at%203.13.45%20AM.png

Comment: Do you want them to get smaller, or do you want the container to scroll? I'll see if I can figure something out based on your answer.

Comment: I'd like the container to scroll. (It scrolls a minimal amount currently)

Comment: I updated the code, by adding `-webkit-flex-shrink` to the `.gallery a`. I think there are some quirks in other browsers (like having to manually set this as part of the `flex` property itself), but hopefully this will lead you down the right road.

Comment: Good luck. [This](http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/) is a good article on mixing multiple versions of flexbox, and [this](http://weblog.bocoup.com/dive-into-flexbox/) article goes in depth on all the different properties and values.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the images within a div positioned in absolute and place it at the bottom like

```
<div>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/ff0000" />
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/ff0000" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
img {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

Check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cdr33/)

Comment: As I mentioned, "I can't encase them in their own div because when clicked, the targeted image is supposed to go to the top of the page"

Answer (score 0):

Set CSS on your `<a>` -

```
.gallery a{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width:30px;    
}
```

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/ScbBf/)

After Update -

[Try This also](http://jsfiddle.net/ScbBf/1/)

Comment: This causes the targeted image to no longer stay in the center?

Comment: I didn't understand what you want. Please see updated "jsfiddle".

Comment: I'd like the targeted image to be horizontally centered. For some reason (using Safari), the selected image is offset from the center